# Struct visible only within a class/ code file ruby

Tags: ruby, struct, scope

I want to use structs within my classes to save on memory, but I want my code to be easily used by others.
Say I want to use a new Struct, name it "KE". I want this Struct to be only visible from within a class I, that would be use it. I.e., if anyone who uses my code defines elsewhere class/struct "KE", it won't override my "KE", and mine won't override theirs. Having it in the same code text file is good too.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Perhaps adding a code example would help? But to avoid naming collisions you usually wrap your code into modules to namespace them.

Comment: I think that you just helped me. I need to look at modules. It looks like the way to go ( I have used namespaces in TCL). I am a hardware engineer, and I am doing coding work as means to improve my productivity, therefore I have a lot of holes in my SW skillset. Thanks!

Comment: "I want to use structs within my classes to save on memory" – `Struct::new` does nothing more than dynamically generate a class at runtime, so a `Struct` uses exactly as much memory as a class would. In fact, some Ruby implementations are not capable of optimizing dynamically generated classes in the same way they optimize statically created ones, so depending on which implementation you use, a `Struct` may even use more memory than a class.

Comment: Oh, good know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your code into a [module](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html) which will act as a namespace, e.g.:

```
module Foo
  KE = Struct.new(:name)

  # remaining code
end
```

Within the `Foo` namespace you can refer to the struct just via `KE`, e.g.:

```
module Foo
  # ...

  def self.build_ke(name)
    KE.new(name)
  end
end

Foo.build_ke('abc')
#=> #<struct Foo::KE name="abc">
```

Outside of `Foo` however, you have to use the `Foo::` prefix:

```
Foo::KE.new('def')
#=> #<struct Foo::KE name="def">
```

Other `KE` constants won't interfere with your `KE`:

```
KE = :top_level

module Bar
  KE = :nested_in_bar
end

KE      #=> :top_level
Bar::KE #=> :nested_in_bar
Foo::KE #=> Foo::KE          # <- your struct
```

---

To "hide" the struct, you could make the constant private via [`private_constant`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#private_constant-method):

```
module Foo
  KE = Struct.new(:name)
  private_constant :KE

  def self.build_ke(name)
    KE.new(name)
  end
end

Foo.build_ke #=> #<struct Foo::KE name="abc">
Foo::KE      #=> NameError: private constant Foo::KE referenced
```

Or you could use an anonymous struct by not assigning it to a constant in the first place, e.g. via a private class method:

```
module Foo
  def self.ke_class
    @ke_class ||= Struct.new(:name)
  end
  private_class_method :ke_class

  def self.build_ke(name)
    ke_class.new(name)
  end
end

Foo.build_ke('abc') #=> #<struct name="abc">
Foo.ke_class        #=> NoMethodError: private method `ke_class' called for Foo:Module
```

Comment: Hi. That's almost exactly what I need, definitely doable. So, congrats.
However, if there a way to make KE invisible to other bits of the code (from different files), it would be ideal. Thanks again.